# Do we need to perform a certificate signing request (CSR) for personal digital certificate?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, csr

Or is there an official equivalent? For example, in S. Korean banks, there's a need for every individual to own a digital certificate before they can access online/mobile banking. There's some sort of a procedure. But I wish to know if there's a standard to this request.

Answer (score -3):

In the case of online and mobile banking in South Korea, the requirement for individuals to possess a digital certificate is specific to the country's banking regulations and security practices. It is not a globally standardized practice.

In South Korea, the government has implemented a system called "Public Key Certificate-based Authentication" for secure online transactions, including banking. This system requires individuals to obtain a digital certificate, often referred to as a Public Key Certificate (PKC), to authenticate their identity and ensure secure communication between the user's device and the banking system.

The process for obtaining a digital certificate for online and mobile banking in South Korea typically involves the following steps:

1. Personal Identification: Individuals need to present their identification documents, such as a resident registration card or passport, to verify their identity.
2. Certificate Issuance Request: Users submit a request for a digital certificate to the designated certificate authorities approved by the Korean Financial Services Commission (FSC). These authorities are responsible for issuing and managing digital certificates.
3. Identity Verification: The certificate authority performs identity verification based on the provided identification documents. This process may involve in-person verification at a registration center or through an online verification system.
4. Certificate Issuance: Upon successful identity verification, the certificate authority issues a digital certificate to the individual. The certificate is typically stored on a smart card or USB device and is protected with a password.
5. Certificate Registration: The issued digital certificate needs to be registered with the online banking service or mobile banking application provided by the user's bank. This registration process associates the digital certificate with the user's banking account.

It's important to note that the specific procedures and requirements for obtaining a digital certificate may vary among different banks or certificate authorities within South Korea.

It is not a universally mandated practice, and each country or organization may have its own security measures and authentication methods in place.

Comment: Thanks but my question is not about S. Korea.

Comment: IF you read the response, you would see that I answered your questions clearly.

Comment: don't bother, this is AI generated